# Add trailing slash to single directory in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Im currently trying to redirect a directory so that it adds a trailing slash at the end of the URL. I have tried

```
Redirect 301 /category/blog http://www.example/category/blog/
```

and

```
Redirect 301 http://www.example.co.uk/category/blog http://www.example.co.uk/category/blog/
```

However this causes an infinite loop whereby a trailing slash keeps getting appended to the end of the URL so it eventually becomes http://www.example.co.uk/category/blog/////////

Please note I only want to target this URL and no other URLs.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit to an exact match, rather than a prefix match, with RedirectMatch:

```
   RedirectMatch ^/category/blog$ http://www.example/category/blog/
```